# Python: Use itertools and access tuple items separately in loop

Tags: python, loops, tuples, combinations, python-itertools

Working in Python, I have a list of strings. I'd like to iterate over all combinations of strings, and pass each combination as two of three arguments to a function. Also, I'm trying to use itertools.

This is what I initially came up with:

```
for pair in itertools.combinations(stringList,2):
    function(*pair[0],*pair[1],0)
```

This doesn't work. After some trying around, my last idea is turning `*pair` into a string, then splitting it into a list, and accessing its items - but that seems wrong on so many levels. Any advice?

Comment: Why not `for a, b in ...: function(a, b, 0)`? You can't have positional arguments after `*`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me :

```
 for pair in itertools.combinations(string_list, 2):
     print(pair[0], pair[1])
```

And can also be written using tuple unpacking:

```
 for e1, e2 in itertools.combinations(string_list, 2):
     print(e1, e2)
```

I'll let you adapt this to your code.